# How to wrap the content of a child div, possibly with a scroll, inside a parent div with max height?

Tags: html, css

I would like the `#child` `div` to be inside `#parent` one, and when the content exceeds the max height, there should be a scroller in `#list` when the actual content exceeds the max height. The max height is a percentage of `#wrapper` height.

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

#parent {
  max-height: 40%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#child {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

#list {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
      <div>Header is not supposed to be scrollable</div>
      <div id="list">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: you could relay on grid or flex system to let the browser do the math for height and make inhertable evn if not specified. But Do you really need so many containers inside each others ?  an example from your code https://jsfiddle.net/ce1wyqhb/ probably irrelevant without knowing what you're after really  (30% of 100vh is 30vh ;)  so max-height:30vh + overflow on #list is plenty enough i guess)

Comment: hello, I want only #list scrollable not #child or #parent. I've edited the snippet to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: it is actually the case : https://jsfiddle.net/gkn0xqmj/1/

Comment: Looks like there's no header in the fiddler.

Comment: no there was not, it was first a comment (and question) giving you an hint . so now if we follow your logic, child is 40vh of height and header 20px of height .... I still do not get the point of your structure and what is supposed to come below #parent ? Off i go back on duty. i'll read you again in a few hours.

Comment: Hi @HenokTesfaye, check my answer below and let me know it's what you are looking for please :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, just apply the Overflow-y property to #Parent instead of #List.

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

#parent {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 30%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#child {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

#list {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
      <div id="list">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hello,  `#list {max-height:30vh;overflow:auto; }`  should do and be the simpliest

Answer (score 0):

You make use of [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) here, and you would get the behavior you want, as far as I understood at least:

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

#parent {
  max-height: 40%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

#child {
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
 
}

#list {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
      <div>Header is not supposed to be scrollable</div>
      <div id="list">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```